# support for check constraint for foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables in database

```
Employee(emp_id,emp_name,salary,dept_id)
Department(dept_id,dept_name,location)
```

dept_id in Employee table is foreign key references on Department(dept_id)

I want to ask if I can make these constraint or not

(when inserting a row in employee table, the dept_id must found in department table, if it is not found >> it's automatically inserted in department table)
Can I make this using check constraint, if yes, how? if no, why?

Thanks

Comment: Where/who is determining the department? Show your INSERT query into Employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, constraints cannot do inserts into other tables.   To do what you want, you need to write a `Trigger`.